# Does this smell if I cant decide which descendant should I use?

Tags: php

```
abstract class X
{
    private $v;

    protected function setV($v)
    {
        $this->v = $v;
    }

    public function getV()
    {
        return $v;
    }
}

class A extends X
{
    public function doIt()
    {
        parent::setV(1);
    }
}

class B extends X
{
    public function doIt()
    {
        parent::setV(2);
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->doIt();

$b = new A();
$b->doIt();
```

but if I want to use `getV()`, I can both call

`$a->getV()` and `$b->getV()`

- which sounds silly. Which one to use? To be honest, I would like to see something like that:

  X::getV();

which is not possible, an instance must be exists/

Comment: Please edit **your question** to clarify: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Do you want this to be a single, class-wide value?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on "what do you want". Firstable, it's possible to use `X::getV()` method, but you need to make `v` member and `getV` method static, as shown below.

```
<?php

abstract class X
{
    private static $v;

    protected static function setV($v)
    {
        self::$v = $v;
    }

    public static function getV()
    {
        return self::$v;
    }
}

class A extends X
{
    public function doIt()
    {
        self::setV(2);
    }
}

class B extends X
{
    public function doIt()
    {
        self::setV(1);
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->doIt();

echo X::getV();
// prints 2
// but be aware, that ANY instance of X children class will change the same X::$v value
$b = new B();
$b->doIt();

echo X::getV();
// prints 1
```

Static members (like `X::$v`) are stored only once, they are "binded" to the class, not to the instance of this class.

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    public static $v = 5;
}

$instance1 = new Foo();
$instance2 = new Foo();
echo Foo::$v;
echo $instance1::$v;
echo $instance2::$v;
// prints 5, 5, 5

$instance1::$v = 10;
echo Foo::$v;
echo $instance1::$v;
echo $instance2::$v;
// prints 10, 10, 10
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not considered good answers on this site, and with good reason. Please explain how you addressed the problem, and why.

Comment: @alexis, sorry, I deleted my explanation just before posting (ctrl-a, ctrl-v). Edited the answer.

Comment: Ok, downvote reversed! But "V" is now a static value, and you should be explicit about what that means in practical terms. (I know that's what the comment is for, but still.) On the other hand, who even knows if that's what the OP was trying to do?

Comment: GetV should be asked from X itself, not from any of its descendant

Comment: @JohnSmith, am I right that you want to restrict calling `getV` on its descendants?

Comment: @alexis, I will add a more detailed explanation about static members, but firstly I want to clarify what behavior exactly OP wants to achieve :)

Comment: @JohnSmith, I can suggest you such a solution https://gist.github.com/kaduev13/79338b614a79c29988ff1318072d58d8, but note that it's VERY VERY dirty (it breaks OOP paradigms) and you should have really important reasons to use this hack.

Comment: @kaduev13 the opposite

Comment: @JohnSmith, so, you want to allow calling `getV` only from descedants? Can you please update your question with description of behavior that you want? It's not clear to me so far :(